# problem with chrome autofill suggestion in certain path url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

there is in an search input in my header and in all pages like ***/about*** and ***/home*** and etc it works fine. but as soon as i go to the ***/account*** page chrome autofill suggestion pops up and want me to click on one the items and in some cases it automatically fill the input search with username which is worse.

this behavior appears in chrome only. i need to some how turn it off and i already tried `autocomplete="chrome-off"` and `autocomplete="off"` but nothing seems to work find.

is this a bug ?

Comment: it seems [chrome always making new stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off).

Comment: yea i saw this answer, but all answers try to turn it off but my problem is it is just triggers in ```/account``` page.

Answer (score 0):

use `autocomplete='new-password'` to disable auto fill

Comment: auto-fill is off all over the application but it triggers in ```/account```