# autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="new-password" are not working

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vuejs3, v-autocomplete, password-autofill

I have a project I've created by vuejs 3 and I'm trying to use the autocomplete with value off and new-password even with false value but they're not working in my case so I have tried a lot of methods like installed library called vue-disable-autocomplete but the library is added the readonly='readonly' attribute for the inputs even when focused stills the readonly attribute so I tried to add function for on focus delete the readonly attribute but when it's deleted immediately adding the autofill

any helps, I'll I'll appreciate it

Comment: I think `autocomplete=off` is for the browser. Extensions like 1pass and lasspass don't respect those.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature of your browser, if the browser detect that X textbox is for a Account-Password, it will activate the autocomplete on no matter what you do witjh autocomplete. It could help to use other name instead og password, to see if the browser dont detect it.

There is a related topic where it give better explanation:
[Chrome ignores autocomplete="off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off?rq=2)