# Turning autocomplete off on an HTML element is not working

Tags: html

I'm having a problem using the autocomplete attribute on my HTML `<input>` element.

I was expecting it to turn off auto fill. I have done research and even went to AI for last resort, but nothing is working.

Here is the full `<input>` code I'm using:

```html
<input id="addAUserInput" onkeyup="searchUser()" placeholder="add a user (type their username)" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
```

Here is the parent code:

```js
function searchUser() {
  return "";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #00adf1;
  color: white;
}

.addAUser {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0088cc;
}

.addAUser .at-sign {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.addAUser input {
  width: calc(100% - 51px);
  background-color: #0088cc;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.addAUser input::placeholder {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.addAUser input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.addAUser .add {
  transform: translate(-5px, 0);
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#addAUserSuggestionList {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  margin-left: -2px;
  display: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#addAUserSuggestionList li {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-style: none solid solid solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #0088cc;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}

#addAUserSuggestionList li:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #0092cf;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="document.getElementById('addAUserSuggestionList').style.display = 'block';" class="addAUser">
  <span class="at-sign">@</span>
  <input id="addAUserInput" onkeyup="searchUser()" placeholder="add a user (type their username)" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" />
  <i onclick="addUser()" title="Add the user" class="add fas fa-plus"></i>
  <ul id="addAUserSuggestionList"></ul>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
```

The HTML looks off but that’s just how Stack Overflow has it

Comment: I made a snippet. Please add relevant CSS and JavaScript

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off?rq=2

Comment: try `<input type="search" autocomplete="off" >` as [@J.T.Taylor suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off/30873633#30873633)

Comment: @MHDAlaaAlhaj nope :(

Comment: How are you determining if it's working or not? I mean, it's not filling in the username of this site, so....?

Comment: @HereticMonkey the auto fill thing is popping up when it’s set off

Comment: In newest Chrome Windows, I cannot reproduce this. If I change your ID `addAUserInput` to `name` which will trigger a lot of MY autocompletes, I DO get autocompletion but ONLY when I REMOVE `autocomplete="off" ` from your HTML. In my Firefox (also latest) I cannot even get the autocomplete to trigger. HOWEVER in EDGE, a space will trigger "saved personal info" if the ID is name

Answer (score 0):

On March 7, 2024,

**Update:** After a lot of feedback, I have concluded that Safari dose not support the autocomplete globe attribute, which resulting in my problem.

*Psst...Apple please fix this!*

Comment: While this answer may seem correct for the question, typically, this would be in the form of an edit on a post.

Comment: @RedYetiDev I had that idea but wanted to make it clear.

Comment: I see, well then, thanks for your contribution to the community, and welcome to StackOverflow. It's nice to have you here!

Comment: @RedYetiDev Thanks! I’m a new guy here and a lot of people bully me on how I do things, thanks for understanding.